# Android Fragment (OnboardingFragment) obtener evento desde Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

En mi `MainActivity` 
como puedo obtener eventos que suceden en uno de mis **fragments** ?

```
public class ManActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_formulario);
//Este boton está dentro de fragment.xml 
Button tvDateB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDate); 
        tvDateB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boton de fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
}
```

Estoy utilizando `OnboardingFragment` y distintas clases de `Onboarding`

//Este es OnboardingFragment
//Esto funciona bien, y cambio de Fragment deslizando.
//Quisiera que ademas de llamar a cada layout tambien llame a la clase : "public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {" y a cada una de las clasesde los Fragment

public class OnboardingFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String PAGE = "page";

private int backgroundColor;
private int page;

public static OnboardingFragment newInstance(int page) {
    OnboardingFragment fragment = new OnboardingFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(PAGE, page);

    fragment.setArguments(b);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    page = getArguments().getInt(PAGE);

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int layoutResId;
    switch (page) {
        case 0:
            layoutResId = R.layout.fragment_1;
            break;
        case 1:
            layoutResId = R.layout.fragment_2;
            break;
        case 2:
            layoutResId = R.layout.fragment_3;
            break;
        case 3:
            layoutResId = R.layout.fragment_4;
            break;
        case 4:
            layoutResId = R.layout.fragment_1;
            break;
        default:
            layoutResId = R.layout.fragment_1;
            break;
    }

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResId, container, false);
    view.setTag(page);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente te sugiero usar [OnboardingSupportFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/OnboardingFragment) en lugar de `OnboardingFragment`, ya que esta marcada como obsoleta desde la API 27.

Para realizar lo que deseas debes crear una `interface`,

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public void myEvent();
}
```

tu `Activity`  que contendra el `Fragment` debe implementar la interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

   @override
   public void myEvent() {
      //....
   }
}
```

y dentro de tu `Fragment` puedes llamar el método que que indica un evento y será "leído" por la Activity

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   MyInterface interface;

   public void setInterface(MyInterface interface) {
      this.interface = interface;
   }

   public void myEvent(View v) {
     //Realiza un evento
     ...
     ...
   }
}
```